# Sending PHP mail from a server without a domain name

Tags: linux

I'm running a wordpress multisite install on a linux AWS ec2 server.

We're having some issues with emails sent via sendmail being blocked by the end user. The issue is generally not a problem with personal email accounts, more so with larger organisations with nasty firewalls.

At the moment, the server doesn't have a public domain name... So I'm not sure how to configure my php.ini file's sendmail_from

Any help would be great!